# How to increase a bubble size of node in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I tried looking the command but unable to increase the bubble size of the node as I want to view the complete text in a bubble.

Comment: Hello! Maybe you can show what you tried so far?

Comment: If you're talking about the neo4j web interface, there is no command; you have to edit the `.grass` file. And you can find more info on this via the Neo4j docs. FYI this question is off-topic here, as it's unrelated to programming, and just a tweak to the Neo4j web interface.

Comment: @iGian - there's nothing for the OP to show - this is a styling question related to the portal / display. There's no command, just a formatting file for them to alter. And unrelated to programming (hence off-topic here).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Oops! I'm sorry. I was supposing there where some sort of config.

Answer (score 5):

You can manually change the display size of nodes in the Neo4j Browser.

Here is an image from the [Neo4j Browser UI Guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization):

[image]

Just select the node label at the top (see #1 in image), and then pick the desired size at the bottom (see #4).